# Setting EditText content

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a a EditText field which allows only decimal numbers. How can I set it's value in the code when I press a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourEdit.setText(String.valueOf(12));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few ways to set the proper value in your `EditText`. Assuming you have it's `@id` being `my_edittext`:

```
final Integer value = 10;
final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
myEditText.setText(value.toString());
myEditText.setText(Integer.toString(value));
myEditText.setText(String.valueOf(value));
// and an ugly one: 
myEditText.setText(value + "");
```